# Read Specific line and columns form a file with TCL/TK

Tags: tcl

I want to read a word from a file with TCL/TK and store it in a variable.

I want to read the word which is located in the file.txt which is located in line number 366 and columns from 19 to 21 and store it in the string variable Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set fp [open src.txt r]
set count 0
while {[gets $fp line]!=-1} {
    incr count
    if {$count==366} {
            break
    }
}
close $fp

puts "Required Line : $line"
set result [string range $line 18 20]
puts "Required word(s) : $result"
```

`string range` indices starting with 0, so I have reduced 1 in each indices

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it getting the line number 25? How do I store that string in the variable "Word"?

Comment: Updated the answer to get it on the line number 366 and it is stored in the variable `result`. Adjust the indices based on your needs.